# Makefile pattern rule with mixed dependencies

Tags: c++, design-patterns, makefile, dependencies

I've coded the following lines in my Makefile:

```
PROJECTS  = ExamsGenerator ExercisesImporter
VERSION   = .v0.0
EXTENSION = .Exe

BINDIR    = ../bin
CONFDIR   = ../config
DATADIR   = ../data
DOCDIR    = ../doc
INCDIR    = ../include
LIBDIR    = ../lib
OBJDIR    = ../obj
SRCDIR    = ../src

INCDIRS   = $(INCDIR:%=-I%)

CC        = g++
CCVAR     = -D__DATADIR__=\"$(DATADIR)\"

CFLAGS    = -g -Wall $(shell root-config --cflags)  $(INCDIRS)
LDFLAGS   = -g -Wall $(shell root-config --ldflags)
LDLIBS    =          $(shell root-config --glibs)

MEG_DEP  = Functions.h Parser.h Test.h
MEG_DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(INCDIR)/%,$(MEG_DEP))

MEI_DEP  = Functions.h Parser.h Exercise.h
MEI_DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(INCDIR)/%,$(MEI_DEP))

MEG_OBJ   = mainExamsGenerator.o Parser.o Test.o
MEG_OBJS  = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(MEG_OBJ))

MEI_OBJ   = mainExercisesImporter.o Parser.o Exercise.o
MEI_OBJS  = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(MEI_OBJ))

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(MEG_DEPS) $(MEI_DEPS)
    @echo "\nCreating object: $@"
    $(CC) $(CCVAR) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

all: $(PROJECTS)
    @echo "\n"

ExamsGenerator: $(MEG_OBJS)
    @echo "\nLinking $@"
    $(CC) $(CCVAR) $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -o $(BINDIR)/$(@)$(VERSION)$(EXTENSION) $^

ExercisesImporter: $(MEI_OBJS)
    @echo "\nLinking $@"
    $(CC) $(CCVAR) $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -o $(BINDIR)/$(@)$(VERSION)$(EXTENSION) $^

.SILENT:

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    \rm -f $(BINDIR)/*$(EXTENSION) $(OBJDIR)/*.o *~ $(INCDIR)/*~ $(SRCDIR)/*~
```

I'm a Makefile newbie so I've picked up hints from several places and I'm probably not writing it in the most elegant way. I have few questions to improve them:

1. Do I really need to add $(OBJDIR)/%.o into the dependencies ?
2. Written in this way Parser.h is listed twice. Is it possible to rewrite this pattern rule to avoid it ? E.g., I don't want to recompile MEG stuff if Exercise.h is modified. New dependencies will be added and I'd like to manage them in a smart way.
3. Any other suggestion?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Bye...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need (and don't want) to list a target as its own prerequisite. That doesn't make sense and cannot work.

`$(patsubst %,prefix/%,$(var))` can be written as `$(addprefix prefix,$(var))`.

You might want to read [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) for a method to automatically generate the correct dependencies for `.o` files. It will help solve some of your problems.

If, however, you don't want to get that fancy then what you need to remember is that you need to list, for each target, *all* the files that that target depends on and no other files.

So

1. `Parser.o` presumably depends on (at least) `Parser.h`

   So add `$(OBJDIR)/Parser.o: $(INCDIR)/Parser.h`
2. `Exercise.o` presumably depends on (at least) `Exercise.h` (and possibly also `Parser.h`?)

   So add `$(OBJDIR)/Exercise.o: $(INCDIR)/Exercise.h` (or possibly `$(OBJDIR)/Exercise.o: $(INCDIR)/Exercise.h $(INCDIR)/Parser.h`)
3. etc...

Note that prerequisites combine from wherever they are found so the above suggested lines will combine with a `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp` rule to form a full set of prerequisites for the given `.o` file.

Comment: I've changed my question and copied the whole Makefile.

Comment: And what if MEG will depend on Function1.h and MEI on Function2.h (with no source file)? In that case the rule
    $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp    
is not enough.

Comment: It *is* enough when you include those prerequisites on other lines as in my answer. You list prerequisites for the targets they are needed by. So if there was a `Function1.o` you would have a `Function1.o: Function1.h` line, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try your suggestions!